# SELECT where column1 = column2

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I've been trying to accomplish the following for the past few hours without any luck:

```
$stmt = $db->query( "SELECT league_match_id as match_id, league_match_home_team as home_team, league_match_away_team as away_team FROM $table WHERE (( home_team = away_team ) AND (away_team = home_team))" );
```

Let's say we have team1 and team2. A match is played where Team1 is home and Team2 is away. Another match (row) is stored where team2 is home and team1 is away. I want to select both of the teams with a single query.

No teams are playing themselves, I am trying to get 2 rows, where the values of home_team and away_team is mirrored.

Can anyone please help me on track?

*** UPDATE ***

The return I am getting is the following:

```
Array
(
   [0] => Array
    (
        [t1_id] => 26
        [t1_home] => 2
        [t1_away] => 1
        [t2_id] => 24
        [t2_home] => 1
        [t2_away] => 2
    )

   [1] => Array
    (
        [t1_id] => 28
        [t1_home] => 3
        [t1_away] => 1
        [t2_id] => 25
        [t2_home] => 1
        [t2_away] => 3
    )

   [2] => Array
    (
        [t1_id] => 24
        [t1_home] => 1
        [t1_away] => 2
        [t2_id] => 26
        [t2_home] => 2
        [t2_away] => 1
    )

   [3] => Array
    (
        [t1_id] => 29
        [t1_home] => 3
        [t1_away] => 2
        [t2_id] => 27
        [t2_home] => 2
        [t2_away] => 3
    )

   [4] => Array
    (
        [t1_id] => 25
        [t1_home] => 1
        [t1_away] => 3
        [t2_id] => 28
        [t2_home] => 3
        [t2_away] => 1
    )

   [5] => Array
    (
        [t1_id] => 27
        [t1_home] => 2
        [t1_away] => 3
        [t2_id] => 29
        [t2_home] => 3
        [t2_away] => 2
    )

)
```

Where both Array[0] and Array[2] is the same, they are just mirrored. Can I get rid of the duplicates here? I would love to have just Array[0] or Array[2]. Is this possible?

Comment: A small example of the data in the table, and what resultset you want returned from that data goes a long way to explaining what you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I doubt there would be any rows where the "home team" is the same as the "away team".

It sounds as if you want to find *two* rows that match.

Based on the conditions in your query, it sounds like you might want something like this:

```
SELECT t1.league_match_id         AS t1_match_id
     , t1.league_match_home_team  AS t1_home_team
     , t1.league_match_away_team  AS t1_away_team
     , t2.league_match_id         AS t2_match_id
     , t2.league_match_home_team  AS t2_home_team
     , t2.league_match_away_team  AS t2_away_team
  FROM $table t1
  JOIN $table t2
    ON t1.league_match_home_team = t2.league_match_away_team
   AND t1.league_match_away_team = t2.league_match_home_team
```

This assumes you have corresponding rows in the table, e.g.

```
 id  home   away
 --  -----  ------
  2  bears  tigers
  3  tigers bears
```

If there are multiple rows with the same (home,away), you'll get multiple matches. For example, with:

```
 id  home   away
 --  -----  ------
  2  bears  tigers
  3  tigers bears
  5  tigers bears
  7  tigers bears
 11  bears  tigers
```

You'd get back a total of twelve rows. (Rows with id values of 2 and 11 will each get "matched" to rows with id values of 3, 5, and 7.)

---

**UPDATE**

Getting rid of duplicates depends on the source of the duplication. Adding a `DISTINCT` keyword will ensure that no two rows in the result set are exactly the same, but I suspect your duplicates issue is deeper than that... where the `bears` and `tigers` have faced each other, home and away, in multiple league matches.

In that case, you'd need something additional in the tables, and some predicate to limit the matches. This could be date, and some method to get the "latest date", but that would depend on what else is in the table.

With just the columns shown, a `GROUP BY` and an aggregate function like `MAX()` can be used to get one distinct row for each "match".

For example:

```
SELECT MAX(t1.league_match_id)    AS t1_match_id
     , t1.league_match_home_team  AS t1_home_team
     , t1.league_match_away_team  AS t1_away_team
     , MAX(t2.league_match_id)    AS t2_match_id
     , t1.league_match_away_team  AS t2_home_team
     , t1.league_match_home_team  AS t2_away_team
  FROM $table t1
  JOIN $table t2
    ON t1.league_match_home_team = t2.league_match_away_team
   AND t1.league_match_away_team = t2.league_match_home_team
 GROUP 
    BY t1.league_match_home_team
     , t1.league_match_away_team
```

Note that returning the `home` and `away` from t2 is redundant, since `t1.home = t2.away` etc. The values from `t1` and `t2` are the same, except that `home` and `away` are swapped.

To limit the "inverse" rows, so you'd get `(bears,tigers)` but not `(tigers,bears)`, you could specify an additional predicate so you only get one "side" of the inverse:

```
AND t1.league_match_home_team < t2.league_match_home_team
```

---

**FOLLOWUP**

(There was a typo error in my query, the first JOIN predicate should have specified `t2.` on the right side. I believe OP found that problem and fixed it.)

Based on the latest update, to eliminate the "mirror" inverse rows in the resultset, you could add a predicate like this (following the `GROUP BY` clause if your query has one.)

```
  HAVING t1_id < t2_id
```

(A `HAVING` clause can reference aliases assigned to the return columns, unlike the `WHERE` clause.)

If you don't have a `GROUP BY` in your query, you're likely to get better performance with a WHERE clause:

```
WHERE t1.match_id < t2.match_id
```

If it doesn't matter which of the two rows you get, then it doesn't matter whether it's a less than or a greater than comparison. It doesn't matter which of the t1 and t2 columns you choose to compare ("id", "home" or "away"), all that is required is a comparison of a column between t1 and t2 that are guaranteed to be different (so you'll get just one side of the mirror.)

Comment: I love this query, it's working as expected but I am getting duplicates. How do I prevent this?

Comment: @Kolind: getting rid of duplicates depends on the source of the duplication. Adding a DISTINCT keyword will

Comment: I've updated my question. I would be happy if you'd have the time to take a look at it. Thanks again :)

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT 
   t1.league_match_id , 
   t1.league_match_home_team , 
   t1.league_match_away_team ,
   t2.league_match_id , 
   t2.league_match_home_team, 
   t2.league_match_away_team   
FROM 
   {$table} t1 JOIN {$table} t2 ON t1.league_match_home_team=t2.league_match_away_team as away_team  AND 
                                   t2.league_match_home_team=t1.league_match_away_team as away_team
 GROUP BY
   t1.league_match_id , 
   t1.league_match_home_team , 
   t1.league_match_away_team ,
   t2.league_match_id , 
   t2.league_match_home_team, 
   t2.league_match_away_team
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have updated my question, since there's been some confusion of what I want to do. The query you've written doesn't provide me with any rows at all.

Comment: It doesn't seem to work out just like that. spencer7593's answer is working, but I am having duplicates.

Comment: Yeah. I am going with spencer7593's answer. It's working great. Thanks a lot for your time tho'.

Comment: Hey @Notulysses... If you've got the time to look at my updated question, it would be awesome. I am having some new "issues" :)